# Отобразить вывод

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Программа компилируется, выполняется, но вывода не видно. В чем может быть причина?[image: Вот такое состояние и остается]

Содержимое файла build.gradle:

> plugins {
>       id 'java' }
>
> version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
>
> sourceCompatibility = 1.8
>
> repositories {
>       mavenCentral() }
>
> dependencies {
>       //testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12' }

В свойствах логов вывод проставил на всякий случай:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так текст градла покажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Dred, добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Допишите в gradle скрипте следующее:

```
apply plugin:'application'
mainClassName = "<полный путь до класса с main методом>"
```

В вашем случае mainClassName = `Whl`

Comment: Для моего случая это будет mainClassName = "Pract.P1.Whl"? Добавил, но результат не изменился

Comment: полный путь должен включать только название пакетов и название класса; Я написал в ответе какое значение должно быть в вашем случае. Т.к. у класса Whl нет пакетов

Comment: Включил в build.gradle модуля P1 apply plugin:'application'
mainClassName = "Whl". Вывод не появился ((

Comment: У вас там два gradle скрипта, удалите тот что в директории PRACT либо в settings.gradle удалите все и допишите только `include 'P2'`

Comment: include 'P1' в setting.gradle прописан. Из директории PRACT удалил build.gradle. Но в Run Tasks есть сообщение :P1:processResources (оно с перечеркнутым серым кружком). Вот изображение: https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2019/7/23/ee301bd430d44d6efa5be985abef62e3-full.png

Comment: вот здесь короткий туториал как сделать так что вам нужно - https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/09/gradle-goodness-run-java-application.html